# Multivariable Hessian for maximum/minimum

Tags: partial-derivative, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

Consider a function like
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{y^2}}$$

It is obvious that the maximum of the function is at $x=y=0$.

However if t we try to apply the second derivative test, we will have to evaluate the Hessian at a point where it is not defined.

It will contains elements such as $$\frac{2(5x^\frac{2}{3}+y^\frac{2}{3}+1)}{9x^\frac{4}{3}(x^\frac{2}{3}+y^\frac{2}{3}+1)^3} $$

The element is not defined at zero, how do we overcome this, do we take the limit of the Hessian matrix at $(0, 0)$ or how exactly?

I am not asking for a solution, rather to a way to just overcome the singularity in the Hessian.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the point $(0,0)$ is not a critical point to be tested for Hessian. In fact there is no critical point: $f_x\ne 0, f_y\ne 0$. The border point $(0,0)$ provides the global max, for which Hessian is not required, unless KKT.

Comment: I edited the question to make it not a borderpoint but still still a critical point.

Comment: It is still not a critical point because $f_x\ne 0$. Try $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}$...

Comment: True, it's not a critical point but it's the maximum of the function; how do we find the maximum in this case?

Comment: For the given function, as you said it is obvious, that is: $x>0,y>0 \Rightarrow f(0,0)>f(x,y)$. For further research: check out Extreme point theorem and Kuhn-Tucker conditions for constrained optimization problems...